# Find all solutions to $a^q\cdot b^p=a\cdot1000+q\cdot100+b\cdot10+p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have come across this equality: 
[image]

And became interested in all possible solutions to:
$$a^q\cdot b^p=a\cdot1000+q\cdot100+b\cdot10+p=\overline{aqbp}$$

Unfortunately I have no idea of how to aproach this problem. Can anyone provide any guidance as to how this can be broken down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force computation shows that this is unique. (In base $10$, at least)

In other bases:

\begin{array}{rl}
(\text{Base }6)&0^0\cdot2^4=16=2\cdot6+4=0024_6\\[2ex]
(\text{Base }8)&0^0\cdot3^3=27=3\cdot8+3=0033_8\\[2ex]
(\text{Base }17)&2^0\cdot10^4=10000=2\cdot17^3+10\cdot17+4=20A4_{17}\\[2ex]
(\text{Base }26)&2^9\cdot9^2=41427=2\cdot26^3+9\cdot26^2+9\cdot26+2=2992_{26}\\[2ex]
(\text{Base }29)&0^0\cdot2^6=64=2\cdot29+6=0026_{29}\\[2ex]
(\text{Base }59)&1^{21}\cdot23^4=279841=59^3+21\cdot59^2+23\cdot59+4=[1,21,23,4]_{59}\\[2ex]
(\text{Base }63)&0^0\cdot4^4=256=4\cdot63+4=0044_{63}
\end{array}